# Accessing List from another Class

Tags: java, arrays

How can i add one array to another from two separate classes, then access it from the main class?
The total list shows [] when printed, but the second class shows all the names.

```
public class Main {

    private static Plane fly = new Plane();
    private static Secondclass sec = new Secondclass();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        sec.addPassenger("John");
        sec.addPassenger("Fatso");
        sec.addPassenger("Lisa");
        sec.addPassenger("Mike");
        sec.addPassenger("Randy");
        sec.addPassenger("Jonathan");

        System.out.println("Total list is "+fly.getTotalList());
        System.out.println("Second class is " + sec.getPassengerNames());
    }
}
________________________________________

public class Plane {
    private Secondclass sec;
    private ArrayList<String> totalList;

    public Plane() {
        this.totalList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void addTotalList() {
        this.totalList.addAll(sec.getPassengerNames());
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTotalList() {
        return totalList;
    }

}
________________________________________

public class Secondclass{
    private ArrayList<String> passengerNames;

    public Secondclass() {
        this.passengerNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPassengerNames() {
        return passengerNames;
    }

    public void addPassenger(String name){
        passengerNames.add(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not adding anything to the Plane class, change your Plane class constructor to accept Sec object as well then say this.sec = sec. Later instantiate the Plane ass after adding values to the sec object. Then call plane.addTotalList()

Answer (score 1):

Two important lines are missing in your code.

- Write a constructor Plane with a reference of the object SecondClass as argument.
- Create a constructor with the sec object passed as argument after adding the values in the sec object.
- Call the plane.addTotalList()

  ```
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class Main {
  private static Plane fly;
  private static Secondclass sec = new Secondclass();

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      sec.addPassenger("John");
      sec.addPassenger("Fatso");
      sec.addPassenger("Lisa");
      sec.addPassenger("Mike");
      sec.addPassenger("Randy");
      sec.addPassenger("Jonathan");

      fly = new Plane(sec);
      fly.addTotalList();

      System.out.println("Total list is " + fly.getTotalList());
      System.out.println("Second class is " + sec.getPassengerNames());
  }
  }

  class Plane {
  private Secondclass sec;
  private ArrayList<String> totalList;

  public Plane(Secondclass sec) {
      this.sec = sec;
      this.totalList = new ArrayList<String>();
  }

  public void addTotalList() {
      this.totalList.addAll(sec.getPassengerNames());
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getTotalList() {
      return totalList;
  }

  }

  class Secondclass {
  private ArrayList<String> passengerNames;

  public Secondclass() {
      this.passengerNames = new ArrayList<String>();
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getPassengerNames() {
      return passengerNames;
  }

  public void addPassenger(String name) {
      passengerNames.add(name);
  }
  }`
  ```

  The output:

Total list is [John, Fatso, Lisa, Mike, Randy, Jonathan]
Second class is [John, Fatso, Lisa, Mike, Randy, Jonathan]